# Why for loop is acting like while loop in C# Arrays?

Tags: c#

this for loop inside arrays is working like while and printing only the second index.
what should i do to make it print only even indexes?
[image]

Comment: Don't post code as screen shot! Use code tags. Also: what does it do and what should it do? Hint: i = +2 is certainly wrong.

Comment: no matter how long car is, it only print index 2 but i got it: i=i+2. thanks y'all

Comment: First: code should be part of your question as _text_ (formatted as `code`), not pasted in as a picture. Second, show us the declaration and initialization of `cars` (e.g.  `var cars = new[]{"ford", "bmw", "vw", "mazda", "audi"}`. Then show us what you are seeing and what you expected to have seen (you may also want to explain why you.mention `while` loops in your question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have inverted the `+=` operator in your for loop. You're saying `i = +2` which is the same as `i = 2`

The correct code would be:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i += 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cars[i]);
}
```

Comment: this worked but the right way is : i=i+2

Comment: `i += 2` is functionally the same as `i = i + 2`
That operator is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#compound-assignment